# How to apply CSS on parent using its child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I want to apply CSS on parent using its child

```
<li>
    <div>
        <label>
            <b style="display: none;">Name and Date of Event*: </b>
        </label>
    </div>
</li>
```

I want to hidden to list. but I don'n know how to Apply CSS.

I used just

```
jQuery("b:contains('Name and Date of Event*:')").css('display','none');
```

But it hidden only `<b>` Tag I want to hide li.

How can I hide parent li using child.Is it Possible.

Answer (score 3):

Use **[.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** function. It accepts a selector and finds the the appropriate ancestor.

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
  $("b:contains('Name and Date of Event*:')").parents('li').css('display','none');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  Li Content
    <div>
        <label>
            <b style="display: none;">Name and Date of Event*: </b>
        </label>
    </div>
</li>
<button id="btn">Hide li</button>
```

Why use `.closest` and not `.parents` ?

**.closest()**

1. Begins with the current element
2. **Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector**
3. The returned jQuery object contains zero or one element for each element in the original set

**.parents()**

1. Begins with the parent element
2. **Travels up the DOM tree to the document’s root element, adding each ancestor element to a temporary collection; it then filters that collection based on a selector if one is supplied**
3. The returned jQuery object contains zero or more elements for each element in the original set

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) OR [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

**Try this**

```
jQuery("b:contains('Name and Date of Event*:')").parents('li').css('display','none');
```

OR

```
jQuery("b:contains('Name and Date of Event*:')").closest('li').css({'display':'none'});
```

Comment: @Shahzad Ditro - Try This

Comment: Should be parents not `parent`